# Difference between two times always returns 2 or bigger

Tags: java, android, duration

I have 2 events in my application. I need the time difference between the two of them so I store the time in a sharedpreferences using this line of code :

```
public static void PutStatus(Context ctx,boolean stat)
{
        if (ctx != null)
        {
        SharedPreferences shr = ctx.getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        shr.edit().putBoolean("SHIFT", stat).commit();
        if (stat) shr.edit().putLong("START_TIME", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
        }



}
```

And then I calculate the difference between the two date and times using this :

```
SharedPreferences shr = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            long time_stamp = System.currentTimeMillis() -  shr.getLong("START_TIME", 0);
            Date data = new Date(time_stamp);
```

The minutes are working great but the hours are 2 hour ahead.

Why is that does it have any connection with timezones ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to get a duration with Java is a little bit complicated. You would create it the following way:

```
import javax.xml.datatype.Duration;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory
...
Duration d = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration(time_stamp);
System.out.println(d.getHours() + "h:" + d.getMinutes() + "m: " + d.getSeconds() + "s");
```

For documentation see [Duration](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/datatype/Duration.html) and [DatatypeFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html).

Comment: I get the following exception : 10-08 10:19:11.398: W/System.err(1381): javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found
Any fix ? The solution seems ok to me...

Comment: @opc0de This seems to be a bug in android. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14379 for bugreport and a hint for a workaround to include Xerces' DatatypeFactory with your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you need time interval,   what about just doing some modulo computations?  An hour is 3600 * 1000 milliseconds,  day is 86400 * 1000.   When you create date this way,  you are creating  date object relative to 1.1.1970 UTC - this may be as well 2 hours off from timezone  where your phone thinks to be.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use two date objects, something like

```
 int diffInDays = (newerDate.getTime() - olderDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```